# change domain.com/folder/stuff to domain.com/stuff using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to 301 redirect

```
domain.com/folder/blah_blah
```

to

```
domain.com/blah_blah
```

How can I do this using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Similar to the other answer, but with the 301 header that bots and browsers both like. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^folder/(.*)$  $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add QSA as well (=append query string)

So the thing in the brackets would look like [R=301,NC,QSA,L]